# Retrieve multiple values ​​in a workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, multiple-values

Here is my problem:

I have Two lists:

Projects:

```
Project Name         Project Manager

  Project1              Name 1

  Project2              Name 2
```

DevTeams:

```
Project(Lookup)       Developer

  Project1             Name 1

  Project1             Name 2

  Project2             Name 3
```

I am getting the following warning message when I try to retrieve field values based on a condition in SharePoint Designer.

***The lookup that you defined is not guaranteed to return a single value. If more than one value is returned, only the first value will be used.***

But in my case, the condition satisfies multiple items and would like to return all the values. How to accomplish that ?

I'll explain...When a user creates an item in a third list, my workflow sends an approval to all the leaders of the projects in which the developer is assigned.

how can i retrieve multiple value?

---

i tried something else...

I tried to use a Workflow type 2010. i saw many more options with it...

SO i decided to create an AD group when a project is created in the list ...
Then, i used "Create group in Active Directory" option...

But when i'm launching the workflow cancels itself and said "Access Denied" in the log.

So i used "Set Active Directory Authentication" option but then i get "User or Password error" but i'm sure the user and password are correct

any help?

Answer (score 1):

For a given dev team or individual developer you can retireve all the projects that they are associated with.

Assuming a 2007 version:

To do this you can put some javascript in a Content Editor Web Part on the forms that you want to use to trigger the workflow.

The js code would use the GetListItems operation of the Lists.asmx web service to retrieve all the Project list items for the selected developer or team. From here you can do one of two things:

1. Add all the Project Managers to a single field within the item that is triggering the workflow. Once the PM details have been written to the field proceed with the normal postback and workflow trigger.
2. Use even more javascript to create a task list item using the UpdateListItems operation of the Lists.asmx web service. This will eliminate the need for a workflow but the Tasks list can be configured to auto-email the Assigned To person.

This can all be done in the browser or with SP Designer.

I don't know about 2010 versions although I think 2013 has an out-of-the-box looping workflow activity.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this warning, if you are not using ID field. The below [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/define-a-workflow-lookup-HA010237830.aspx) will be helpful for you. You can Email the project managers from Event Receiver. If you need more info about how to read lookup field value in Event Receiver use this [link](http://spblog.net/post/2011/07/06/Accessing-SharePoint-lookup-fields-values-in-item-receivers-some-pitfalls.aspx).

Comment: Can i add Event Receiver without visual studio?

Comment: Far as I know - no, only using visual studio.

Comment: Cuz' the problem is i'm only using SharePoint Designer

Comment: Also if you had Visual Studio you would be able to create a customer workflow activity which could return multiple results and loop through them.